# How to get the probability to attain some states givent a transition matrix?

Tags: markov-process, transition-matrix

Let be the following framework :

[image]

- **transition model** : There is an initial state noted
  **start**
  and two final states in (4.3) and (4.2).
  The desired action is performed with a probability of 0.8, but with a probability of 0.2,
  the agent moves at right angles to the desired direction. If the action of the agent prevails
  towards a wall (edge of the grid or obstacle in (2,2), the agent remains in his place.
- **rewards model** : the reward is -0.04 for each state except for both
  terminal states that give +1 or -1.

I want to give the probability of being in each of the states after the sequence after [↑,↑,→] ?

I'm sure I can use a Matrix to compute the probability to have these states  rather than doing $p(i,j|[↑,↑,→]),\forall (i,j)\neq(2,2) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each action $a$ in $A = \{← , ↑ ,  → , ↓\}$ you can compute a transition matrix $T_a$ between every state.

If $P_0$ is a vector with zeroes everywhere and 1 for the dimension representing your initial state, the probability distribution after an action $a$ will be $T_a P_0$. Everything is linear, so if you have multiple actions $T_0, T_1,...T_n$ the probability is given by $T_n T_{n-1} ... T_1 T_0 P_0$.

In your case the actions are ↑, then ↑ then → so the probability distribution is given by $T_→ T_↑ T_↑ P_0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight ! I will try that ! Would it be too much to ask you for an example

Comment: @Marine1 An example of a transition matrix?